# HTML unicode not supporting in nexus Devices?

Tags: javascript, unicode

Hi i was trying to render right long arrow in my web page, this is working in all desktop browsers but doesnot work in nexus Device

this unicode `&#10230;` will display like this ⟶

Small right arrow `&rarr;` is working → in android and web as well

Is there any Work arround ?

Comment: "Will display like this"… – That looks like an arrow to me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @deceze , I have updated the question

Comment: Can it be an issue of used font type?

Comment: How the font affect the unicode ? @reporter

Comment: Then the font does not support the symbol or the code is associated to the same symbol in current font.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use "Font Awesome" css

https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_intro.asp